# Initial value Laplace Transform exercise

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm having trouble with the following exercise

$$ y'' +4y - (4/e^x) = 0 $$

with the initial values:

$$ y(0) = 1 y'(0)=5$$

I used the formula $$ y'' = s^2Y(s) − s*f(0) − f'(0)$$

and got to:

$$ Y(s) = \left(\frac{4 + 5 e^x+se^x}{s^2e^x+e^x}\right) $$

But now I'm stuck. Can't find anything remotely similar in Laplace tables.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your $Y(s)$ is not correct. You probably forgot to take Laplace transform of the term $-4/e^x$.

Comment: You are right. I forgot i had to do that. And what is the Laplace transform of that term and how did you find it? Thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Laplace transform of the term $-\frac{4}{e^x}=-4e^{-x}$ is $-\frac{4}{s+1}$ by the following rule:
$$L\{e^{ax}\}=\frac{1}{s-a}$$

Hence
$$Y(s)=\frac{4+(s+5)(s+1)}{(s^2+4)(s+1)}$$

You will then need to use partial fractions to separate the fraction.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a typo in my exercise but i got to the correct result with your help

Comment: @laplaceishard: Glad it helped.